# Apache static data file caching

Tags: apache, caching, centos7

I have a VPS with Centos 7 and Apache 2.4.  This server acts as a backend data source for a mobile app.  Periodically new data files with unique file names are generated, after which they are never changed.  I am looking for the best way to get Apache to cache these data files in memory without restarting the server each time a datafile is generated.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In apache 2.4 you could use the **mod_cache** module. More infos about this on the official apache website:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/caching.html

Not sure I understand the "*without restarting the server each time a data file is generated*" part!